# GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); is showing Registering app com.example.fbbookresale of senders 742646281XXX

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been searching for days and it seems like many have encountered the same problem.

I have tried to register my application in my device to obtain ID from GCM. I referred [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

I am not able to obtain the ID using GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID), I double checked my Sender ID and it's correct.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
boolean flag=false;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Device is already registered on GCM
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
             Log.v("RegId", regId);
    if (regId.equals("")) {

        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {

        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {


            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                     Map<String, String> prms=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     prms.put("regId", regId);
                    try {
                        post(SERVER_URL,prms);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
```

GCM intent Service is written in main package

```
public class GCMIntentservice extends GCMBaseIntentService{

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentservice() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}


@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + arg1);

}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");  } }
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fbbookresale"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.MainActivity"
        android:label="MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.BuyNSell"
        android:label="" >
        </activity>
         <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.Edit"
        android:label="" >
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbbookresale.Add"
        android:label="Buy" >
        </activity>
          <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.fbbookresale" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
                <service android:name=".GCMIntentservice" />
</application>
```

the logcat is showing

```
11-23 09:34:54.193: D/GCMRegistrar(987): resetting backoff for com.example.fbbookresale
11-23 09:34:54.193: V/GCMRegistrar(987): Registering app com.example.fbbookresale of  senders 742646281XXX

11-23 11:17:27.821: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1046): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
11-23 11:17:27.821: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1046): GCM IntentService class: com.example.fbbookresale.GCMIntentService
11-23 11:17:27.831: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1046): Acquiring wakelock
```

It's not even showing the `Log.v("RegId", regId);` in the verbose.

Answer (score 1):

When I renamed the intent service class to GCMIntentService , as well as in the manifest .GCMIntentService I was able to obtain the registration id in the verbose

Answer (score 0):

`GCMRegistrar` belongs to a deprecated library. It should still work, but you are using it inncorrectly. `GCMRegistrar.register` is asynchronous. The registration ID is returned via the BroadcastReceiver to the `onRegistered` method of `GCMIntentService`. However, your  `onRegistered` method does nothing with that registration ID, so it is never persisted locally by `GCMRegistrar` nor sent to your server.

You shouldn't use an old tutorial as an example. Use the [new GCM Client Demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/), which shows how to use the new registration method (using `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` of the `GooglePlayServices` library).

Comment: i tried the tutorial that you suggested but my app is crashing with the error  "has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView"